# Aptana plugin within Eclipse: All 'Commands' options greyed out

Tags: aptana

I am trying to use the Aptana plugin 3.4.2 within Eclipse 4.3.0 - unfortunately, all the Aptana run commands are greyed out.  From a quick google search I have found lots of people asking the same question but I have failed to find a published answer.  Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

Having posted this some four months ago, I stumbled on the solution after a Fedora upgrade did not go entirely to plan and I needed to re-install Eclipse.

The first issue I discovered is that removing Eclipse using Fedora's package manager leaves the plugins still in the user's home directory within a hidden directory `.eclipse`.  So if Aptana has become corrupted, re-installing Eclipse does not help.  I found it best to un-install Eclipse, and then manually remove the Eclipse plugin directory.

The second thing I discovered is that the Aptana Command menu items are only available within the 'Resource' perspective.  For some reason, Aptana was displaying within Web perspective in my Eclipse.  Although the editor windows appear and work exactly the same, the Command menus are disabled. Switching to the correct perspective did the job.